# Is it possible to have dynamic React components in Static Gatsby page?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

**Problem:**
So I'm trying to have a mostly static Gatsby page, but with one exception being the top right there will be a dynamic component that changes depending on whether the user is logged in or not. Checking whether the user is logged in or not has to be done dynamically because I'm using HTTP cookies and if they don't have one then it has to make REST calls to the service for a new one. The reason I am doing it this way is because the site is mostly static and only this one small login progress thing in the top right is the only dynamic component. Is this possible?

**Things I've tried:**
I've tried followed Gatsby's tutorial on creating a login but the way they do it is check the status and forward to another static site depending on if user is logged in or not.

**Expected result:**
On page load I'd like to have the site be mostly static for faster loading and because most of the page is just displaying content from a CMS and then one component that is dynamically checking the login status of the user. So the component in the top right should have a loading icon when the page loads then a login button if the user is not or user info if they are.

Comment: Gatsby doesn't generate just static site, it generates a web app; you can expect to do anything you would do with normal react code, include sending ajax request on component mount, updating local state, or whatever else

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Apollo for making client side queries: https://www.apollographql.com/

There a demo of using Apollo with Gatsby here https://youtu.be/wNUg1jpj9T0?t=1240

Basically, you can wrap your React component in an ApolloProvider that can access the external API.

Apollo uses GraphQL but you can use a library like `apollo-link-rest` to query a REST endpoint.